# Sourcing vimrc changes vimrc's formatoptions

Tags: vimrc, options

I do `vim .vimrc` and my `vimrc` opens with `formatoptions=jcroql`.

Then I do `:source .vimrc` and check the `formatoptions` again; they changed to `tcq`.

As far as I know there's nothing in my file that changes `formatoptions`... and even if there were it should already happen when I open it the first time, right? So how come it opens one way and when I source it it changes to another? Is this supposed to happen? How do I fix it?

Comment: Run `:verbose set fo` and see what set it last.

Comment: @muru `Last set from ~/.vimrc`. Weird...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`:h formatoptions`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27formatoptions%27) says:

```
                                        'formatoptions' 'fo'
'formatoptions' 'fo'    string (Vim default: "tcq", Vi default: "vt")
                        local to buffer
                        {not in Vi}
…
        NOTE: This option is set to the Vi default value when 'compatible' is
        set and to the Vim default value when 'compatible' is reset.
```

So, if your `vimrc` contains `set nocompatible`, it's likely that caused Vim to set `fo` to the Vim default (`tcq`).

For example, try these commands:

```
set formatoptions=jcroql
set nocompatible
set formatoptions
```

The output is:

```
  formatoptions=tcq
```

Comment: Ah, that's it, thanks! When I first open the file, `vim.vim` is sourced after `vimrc`, so the options are set right. So now I need a way to re-source the `ftplugin`s after I source `vimrc`, so I can map a key to do both one after the other. Any ideas?

Comment: Probably set the filetype again? Something like `:let &ft=&ft`

Comment: Yes, something like that... but unfortunately not that, it does nothing. And `:set ft=&ft` sets the `filetype` to "&ft".

Comment: Are you sure it does nothing? In my case, it resets `fo` to `croql` (my original setting for vim files).

Comment: Oops, you're right! I must have made a typo or something. That's perfect, thank you!